# Leaflet trigger popup on feature

Tags: javascript, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

I have a geojson layer in leaflet and I would like to trigger a popup on a specific feature. When declaring the geoJson layer I already have an onEachFeature property which will trigger the popup on click. This works great.

```
onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    layer.bindPopup('<div><h1>' + feature.properties.name + '</h1></div><div>' + feature.properties.description + '</div>');
  }
```

I would like to trigger this popup programmatically though, say on an event. How would I go about that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You have to select the needed layer and call `.openPoup()` method. For example:

```
var geoJson = L.geoJson(geoJsonData, {
  onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(map);
geoJson.getLayer(layerId).openPopup()
```

I've made a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/wz3Lj7v4/15/ . The main issue is how you get the layer that you need. You can look towards [`.getLayer()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup-getlayer), [`.getLayers()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup-getlayers) and [`.eachLayer()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup-eachlayer) methods.